# Can I declare a PreferenceActivity with an IntentFilter action of "Main" and category of "Launcher"?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-preferences

My app will have no user interface at all (exept for notifications) except for the Preferences screen. Can I make the Preferences screen the "main" screen/what the user sees when they 2-click my app's icon?

I can't find any examples that do that, and googling for guidance just turns up all kinds of 3rd-party Launcher comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, just add the relevant intent-filter to the activity

```
  <activity
        android:name="android.preference.cts.PreferenceFromCodeActivity" >
          <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```